# Pass data to previous activity and move to next using same button

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I have three activities. Lets say activity1, activity2 and activity3. I have a button on activity2, on clicking that button I want to send some data to activity1 and move on to activity3. 
I have successfully passed the data from 2 to 1 using:

```
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent updateCounter = new Intent();
            updateCounter.putExtra("counter", Integer.toString(1));
            setResult(RESULT_OK,updateCounter);
            finish();
            }
        });
```

And I can move from activity 2 to 3 using:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent A2_A3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),activity3.class);
        startActivity(A2_A3);
    }
});
```

On same button listener, I want these two tasks. How to implement this?

Comment: Fire up the same intent `A2_A3` in your `onActivityResult()` in `Activity1`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Comment: Oh, okay, glad it worked. Was typing the answer, you can also use `startActivityForResult()` for such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start activity **2** for a result from **1** using `startActivityForResult(intent_a1_to_a2, FETCH_RESULT_FROM_A2)` like this:

`Intent intent_a1_to_a2 = new Intent(mContext, Activity_2.class);
intent_a1_to_a2.putExtra("key","value");
startActivityForResult(intent_a1_to_a2, FETCH_RESULT_FROM_A2);`

Now, in Activity **2**, in the button's listener, you set the code for an intent to `RESULT_OK`, which you've already done. No need to mention here.

After that, you'll be in your Activity **1**'s `onActivityResult()` with request code **FETCH_RESULT_FROM_A2**, you can have the data returned by Activity **2** and just start the Activity **3** over here.